# Is there a default limit to data that can be requested at one time via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, limit

After reading some posts (pun intended) about the possible `-post-max-size` limit when *uploading* data to a server via an `XMLHttpRequest`, I couldn't help but wonder if any `-post-max-size` limitations exist when *requesting* data from a server via XHR.

The answer seems simple (as in, 'obviously not, aside from DDOS'), but I don't know the respective browser implementations of `XHR`. Knowing IE, it could be just 1MB. Who knows?
I ask this because it hasn't come up in any of the discussions I have read so far, or in the search bar. Sorry if it's a duplicate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` by itself doesn't have a limit beside what can be held in memory. However your server will limit it's output. For example, Google App Engine states that the request size limit is 1mb. However some browsers force limits. Firefox employs a 4k limit, however i do not know about other browsers.